# Building an associative array with table row values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, associative-array

I'm trying to build and array with the values of the table row that the user clicks.

so right now I have all of this inside a

```
$('#myDiv').find('tr').click(function(){
```

and assign variables to columns in the table on the row the user clicks

```
var firstName = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text();     
var middleName = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();        
var lastName = $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
```

so now I'm trying to put those in an array

```
var userRow = [];
userRow['firstName'] = firstName;
userRow['middleName'] = middleName;
userRow['lastName'] = lastName;
```

so the thing is, the user is able to click on multiple table rows. When the click a row it toggles a class 'highlight' in the row (which changes the background color of the row)

I'm stuck on creating a loop so that all of the rows they click get added into another array. Kind of like this-

```
Array1 {
      userRow {
            'firstName' = ...;
             ect...
      }
}
```

so when I reference Array1 it'll show me all of the information that I've grabbed from all of the rows with the 'highlight' class, which I've put in the array 'userRow'

I've read on javascript arrays, but like I said I'm stuck and could use some help. It is much appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT: I'm leaving right now, I will be back on tomorrow to choose an answer. thanks all of you for helping me understand this**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in javascript are indexed, not associative. However, javascript objects behave pretty much like an associative array. Therefore, you can do this:

```
var userRow = {}; // curly brackets!
userRow['firstName'] = firstName;
userRow['middleName'] = middleName;
userRow['lastName'] = lastName;
```

Then, you can normally add this userRow object into another array:

```
var Array1 = [];
Array1.push(userRow);
```

Comment: would I need to put in a loop somewhere so that Array1 holds **all** of the rows that have the highlight class? because when I `console.log(Array1);` it only logs the row I last clicked on. Or should I move this outside of the `.click(function() {` ?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have associative arrays. The syntax that looks like an associative array is actually bracket notation for objects. So `myObj.prop1` and `myObj['prop1']` are exactly the same.

I think you want something like this:

```
var selectedRows = $.map($('#myDiv tr.highlight'), function(row, idx) {     
    $row = $(row);
    return {
        firstName : $row.find('td:nth-child(1)').text(),   
        middleName : $row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text(),   
        lastName : $row.find('td:nth-child(3)').text()
    };
});
```

`selectedRows` will be an array containing a number of objects with the keys `firstName`, `middleName`, and `lastName`.

Comment: so I've just tried your code, but seem to be getting 'null' with my `console.log(selectedRows.firstName);` and even tried `console.log(selectedRows['firstName']);` just in case

Comment: `selectedRows` is an array, so try `selectedRows[0].firstName`

Comment: Or you could just `console.log(selectedRows)` to see the whole structure.

Comment: for whatever reason both `console.log(selectedRows);` and `console.log(selectedRows[0]);` do not even show up on the console. I tested and `console.log('test');` does

Comment: actually, double clicking the row toggles the console.log. selectedRows[0] shows undefined and selectedRows shows blank

Comment: @NSchleder See my edit. I didn't realize the `row` parameter was a DOM object, I assumed it would be a jquery object. Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PGPnj/

Answer (score 0):

JS-array don't support string keys.
Use objects instead:

```
var userRow = {};
userRow.firstName = firstName;
userRow.middleName = middleName;
userRow.lastName = lastName;
```

After that you can push `userRow` to `Array1`:

```
Array1 = [];
Array1.push(userRow);
```

Or use objects again:

```
WrapObj = {};   // like Array1 but object
WrapObj.someId = userRow;
```

Comment: Only problem I have with this code is when I `console.log(Array1);` it doesn't hold every row with the highlight class, just the one I last clicked. I need the array to hold all of the rows that are clicked- do I need to put in a loop somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like that.

I'll code something simple and in the way you wrote, so you can understand it easily.

```
var arr;

$('#myDiv').find('tr').click(function(){

   // initialize array
   if (typeof(arr) == 'undefined')) {
       arr = new Array();
   }); 

   // read values
   var firstName = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text();     
   var middleName = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();        
   var lastName = $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').text();

   // create your object
   var yourObject = {
       'firstName' : firstName,
       'middleName' : middleName,
       'lastName' : lastName
   };

   // add your object to the array
   arr.push(yourObject); 
});
```